# What is the semantically correct way to write anchors displayed as block with padding in a table?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Here's the html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th><a href="...">Number</a></th>
        <th><a href="...">Description</a></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td><a href="...">1234</a></td>
        <td>... description</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now adding padding to `table a { display: block; padding: 5px; }` causes problems when I want to also add the same padding to the td's `table td { padding: 5px; }`.  Maybe I'm over using the padding?

I've worked around it in a number of ways by doing: `<th><a href="...">1234</a></th>` and then the css only applies to th elements and not td's.  And I've also added a `class="nolink"`, but I feel that the th methodology is a bit more semantic than using a class describing its content.

This all comes from the problem that in CSS (that I'm familiar with), there is no way to say, style all td's one way **unless** an anchor is a descendant.  I noticed the `:not` selector in CSS3, but I'm not sure I understand how to use it in this case?

**Update:** The problem really is that the padding is added twice to cells with an anchor tag

I didn't explain the actual problem very well, please see this:

http://cssdesk.com/VCtfN

You'll notice the padding when hovering over the links.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem/set up a demo? I fail to _clearly_ understand the problem... >_<

Comment: @kraz done and updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`A` tags are inline elements. Use `display:block` if you want to use margin and padding.

```
table a { padding: 5px; display:block }
```

Comment: Sorry, meant to add `display: block` into the css.  This is _not_ the actual problem.

Comment: I updated my question to point at the actual problem.  The padding is doubled in the case where the cell contains an anchor tag.

Comment: Well yes, it makes sense that it would double - you have two elements that each have padding. If you don't want this, remove the padding from the A tag.

Comment: I know.  But the problem is that padding on the a tag makes links look better with background color changes on hover.  I may have assumed too much in my question... I'll add that too.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions to this problem :

1. Add the padding to the `td` and `th`, but not to the `a`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G8ULx/)
2. Encapsulate all anchorless content withing some block element with a `5px padding` and remove all padding from td/th. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G8ULx/1/)

Comment: as far as #2 goes, it feels wrong doesn't it?  Just to add an element for the sake of padding?  I was thinking along the lines of using the `:not` selector somehow, but I don't know if it makes sense in this case.  And #1 seems to not address the obvious "ugliness" associated with the background color not filling the entire cell.

Comment: Adding an element for the sake of styling isn't wrong at all. You want to add padding to what is inside your cell and __you can't target text node in CSS__, so you might has well add one element. Even with the `:not` CSS selector, you'll have to add a node. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/G8ULx/2/).